# XSLT Nested Elements

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm stuck on using XSLT to transform XML to HTML, where the records in the XML contain multiple nested elements with the same name, but different tags, labels and content.

My XML contains records like:

```
<catalog>
    <catalogKey>77971</catalogKey>
    <yearOfPublication>1999</yearOfPublication>
    <marc>
        <marcEntry tag="035" label="Local system #" ind="  ">77971</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="035" label="Local system #" ind="  ">DIT87496</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind=" 0">3D Studio MAX 3 fundamentals [electronic resource].</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="260" label="Publication info" ind="  ">Indianapolis, Ind. : New Riders, 1999.</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="300" label="Physical descript" ind="  ">1 computer laser optical disk</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="500" label="General Note" ind="  ">Use with book: 3D Studio MAX 3 fundamentals / Michael Todd Peterson</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="520" label="Abstract/summary" ind="  ">&quot;The CD-ROM is loaded with .MAX and .AVI files to follow along with the tutorials, including plug-ins, images, sample animations, models, and textures. Bonus Lotus ScreenCam movies are included to enhance the learning process by providing a visual reference for each tutorial.&quot;</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="538" label="Technical details" ind="  ">CD-ROM disk</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="650" label="Subject term" ind=" 0">Computer graphics--Computer programs.</marcEntry>
        <marcEntry tag="650" label="Subject term" ind=" 0">3d studio (Computer program)</marcEntry>
    </marc>
    <call>
        <item>
            <copyNumber>1</copyNumber>
            <itemID>DUT2000-2102</itemID>
            <library>STEVEBIKO</library>
            <libraryDescription>Alan Pittendrigh Library (Steve Biko Campus)</libraryDescription>
            <location>DISCARD</location>
            <homeLocation>DISCARD13</homeLocation>
            <price currency="R" >80.25</price>
            <category1>CDROMS</category1>
            <type>MMSTLN</type>
            <numberOfPieces>1</numberOfPieces>
            <dateCreated>2005-11-11</dateCreated>
            <isPermanent>true</isPermanent>
        </item>
    </call>
</catalog>
```

I need this to display in HTML like:

```
77971   1999    035 77971
                035 DIT87496
                245 3D Studio MAX 3 fundamentals
                ...
                        1   DUT2000-2102    STEVEBIKO   DISCARD DISCARD13   80.25   CDROMS  MMSTLN  1   2005-11-11
```

But the best I've been able to achieve is:

```
77971   1999    77971
                        1   DUT2000-2102    STEVEBIKO   DISCARD DISCARD13   80.25   CDROMS  MMSTLN  1   2005-11-11
```

with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="report/catalog">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="catalogKey"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="yearOfPublication"/></td>
                <xsl:for-each select="marc">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="marcEntry"/> 
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="call">
                <xsl:for-each select="item">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="copyNumber"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="itemID"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="library"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="location"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="homeLocation"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="category1"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="type"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="numberOfPieces"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="dateCreated"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>  
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I need help with is transforming multiple nested elements with the same name but different tags and content to HTML. The marcEntry tags will vary between records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're going for something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <xsl:for-each select="report/catalog">
            <xsl:variable name="currentCatalog" select="." />
            <xsl:variable name="marcEntries" select="marc/marcEntry" />


            <xsl:for-each select="$marcEntries">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$currentCatalog/catalogKey"/>
                  </xsl:if>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$currentCatalog/yearOfPublication"/>
                  </xsl:if>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@tag" />
                </td>
                <td colspan="10">
                  <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="call">
              <xsl:for-each select="item">
                <tr>
                  <td/>
                  <td/>
                  <td/>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="copyNumber"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="itemID"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="library"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="location"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="homeLocation"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="category1"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="type"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="numberOfPieces"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="dateCreated"/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>  
          </xsl:for-each>

        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on your sample input (after wrapping it with `<report>` tags), the output is the following (click **Run code snippet** to view it rendered):

```html
<html>
  <body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>77971</td>
    <td>1999</td>
    <td>035</td>
    <td colspan="10">77971</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>035</td>
    <td colspan="10">DIT87496</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>245</td>
    <td colspan="10">3D Studio MAX 3 fundamentals [electronic resource].</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>260</td>
    <td colspan="10">Indianapolis, Ind. : New Riders, 1999.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td colspan="10">1 computer laser optical disk</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td colspan="10">Use with book: 3D Studio MAX 3 fundamentals / Michael Todd Peterson</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>520</td>
    <td colspan="10">"The CD-ROM is loaded with .MAX and .AVI files to follow along with the tutorials, including plug-ins, images, sample animations, models, and textures. Bonus Lotus ScreenCam movies are included to enhance the learning process by providing a visual reference for each tutorial."</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>538</td>
    <td colspan="10">CD-ROM disk</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>650</td>
    <td colspan="10">Computer graphics--Computer programs.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>650</td>
    <td colspan="10">3d studio (Computer program)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>DUT2000-2102</td>
    <td>STEVEBIKO</td>
    <td>DISCARD</td>
    <td>DISCARD13</td>
    <td>80.25</td>
    <td>CDROMS</td>
    <td>MMSTLN</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2005-11-11</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!